# In react-table I want to apply sorting only on arrow icon not on whole table header

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am new to react-table.Currently,My sorting is working fine,but it is apply in whole header.[image: Like this].But i Want to apply it only on arrow.
[image: Like this]

```
My code is like this:-
```

```
<th
{...headerProps}
{...attributes}
ref={setNodeRef}
style={{...headerProps.style, ...style}}
>
{id !== 'row-drag-handle' && id !== 'expander' && allowColumnReorder && (
 <div {...listeners} className='columnDragHandle'>
    <DragHandle />
 </div>
)}{' '}
<div style={{padding: '0.4em'}}>
 {render('Header')}
 {canResize && onColumnResize && (
  <div {...getResizerProps()} className='resizer' />
 )}
 {Boolean(onSortChange) && canSort && (
  <span>
  {isSorted ? (
    <Arrow
    fill='white'
    width='10px'
    />
    ) : (
    ''
    )}
  </span>
 )}
 </div>
</th>
```